# Phonegap App build with Phonegap Build alerts with errors on iOS

Tags: jquery, cordova, extjs, phonegap-build

We are developing an app with **Phonegap 2.5.0** (since there is no newer Version in [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)) and are running into troubles.

The app is a simple test app we use to compare jQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch. Therefore we have created an index.html file witch contains links to a jquery.html and a sencha.html implementing the same app with different UI but calling the same phonegap triggers.

We have two build configurations:

- App is built locally via Eclipse
- App is built online via [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)

We use the same web content as on our locally build Android app. We only remove the `<script>` element which loads the *cordova.js* for 2.5.0 and packs the content together with the same config.xml we use in the locally built Android app.
The locally built Android App works just fine. Problems occur only when the app is built online for iOS via Phonegap Build. The Android app built online works, as expected. Only iOS makes troubles.

What happens on iOS:

- index.html is loaded
- we are able to click on the link that switches to the jquery.html or sencha.html.
- after switching the app alerts with some dialogs rotating through following messages:

  1. `gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device455526479"]`
  2. `gap:["NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo","NetworkStatus8103758"]`
  3. `gap:["App","show","App8103759"]`
- then we can access the app and even are able to get the current GPS position.

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot!

Our config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>; <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin=".*"/>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <plugins>
        <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
        <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
        <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
        <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
        <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
        <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
        <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
        <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
        <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
        <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
        <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
        <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
        <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
        <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
        <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
        <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
        <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </plugins>
</cordova>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap Build did only support as newest version cordova 2.5.0. Now it is possible to use the version 2.7.0,too. After switching to 2.7.0 the alert()s have disapeared. Everything works as expected now!

Problem solved!

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you have included the Phonegap JS file which is specific to iOS?? Usually, this error occurs when you wrongly include the cordova/phonegap files (belongs to Android) for iOS development. In the downloaded phonegap 2.5.0 folder, you have different sub folders for different platforms. You have to make sure you use the right Javascript files which are given for specific platforms.

**Possible scenario:**

You might have included the cordova-2.5.0.js file from Android folder to make iOS build. 
You might have just misspelled the JS file in your www folder. (Less possibility though).

**Fix:**

Use the Javascript (Cordova-2.5.0.js file) file from iOS folder inside the Phonegap-2.5.0 folder for iOS build.

Comment: This won't work for us since we must not include any JS file in our project! Your fix is for a locally built app. We are building online with [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/).
According to [Adobe](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app#configure_application) we have to remove the phongegap/cordova JS file to build via [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/). It will include the correct one for the correct platform. So there is no wrong positioned JS file in our project. The problem remains.

Comment: this was the answer for me. I first developed an app for android. When starting on windows phone i forgot to change the cordova.js file.

Comment: Spent almost for finding a fix but this was solution for me. I didn't expect that a Javascript file can be different for two platforms